How do I setup an integration test for a CRUD app for ASP.NET MVC 5 using Entity Framework 6?
I having a functional CRUD app that (simply put) creates, reads, updates, and deletes teachers from a localdb through a GUI.
Regarding create, I have two action results located in the controller:
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ModelTeacher oTeacher)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Return to the view with the validation error messages
        return View(oTeacher);
    }

    db.DbTeachers.Add(oTeacher);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("SuccessCreate", "Teacher");
}

I haven't found resources that click with me on how to test CRUD. I prefer to do an integration test and go through the motion of CRUD so the final test (delete) will remove it from the database. I feel a mock database is not necessary because it is such a small localdb.
My idea to test this controller is to recreate a controller in a test project, create a teacher, and find it and assert it is not null. But it appears that setting up a test environment is not that simple.

You haven't really asked a question yet. What is your practical problem here? For example, "My idea to test this controller is to recreate a controller in a test project, create a teacher, and find it and assert it is not null. But it appears that setting up a test environment is not that simple." Well ... set up a test environment and try. The most basic and straightforward way to start would be to create a database and run your code, where you create a teacher using your application.

Integration tests in ASP.NET Core

If the application mostly does CRUD operations, there's little to be gained from separating what little application code you may have from the database. In that case, I'd consider a self-hosted integration test suite the best fit.
Essentially:

Set up a SQL Server Express or LocalDb database before each test
Run the test
Tear down the database
Repeat

My article Closing database connections during test teardown contains various links to further reading and sample code bases.
